# convergent sequences of functions

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f_{n}$ be a sequence of functions, defined as follows:
a)$f_{n}(x)=\frac{1}{n} \chi_{[0,n](x)}$, $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$;b)$f_{n}(x)=n e^{-nx}\chi_{[0,\infty)(x)}$, also $f_{n}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $;$f_{n}(x)=n\chi_[{0,\frac{1}{n}}](x)$. I have to study if these sequences converge pointwise, almost uniformly or in Lebesgue measure.
For $a)$: I say that $f_{n}$ converge pointwise to $f=1$, because if I fix an $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there are infinitely many $n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that $n>x$. Is that correct?Also, $f_{n}$ does not converge uniformly to $f=1$, because as $n$ goes to $\infty$, I can always find an $x>n$ and for instance $|f_{n}-1|$ is bigger than $1/2$ for infinitely many $x$. Is this correct?

Comment: For the first: If $0\leq x < n$, $f_n(x) = n$. So fix $ x \geq 0$: when $n\to \infty$, $f_n(x)\to\mathbf{?}$ (also, for $ x < 0$, $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$). For b) and c), what is $f_n(0)$? What is the limit?

Comment: I am sorry, I wrote something wrong on the first.

Comment: Still, look at $f_n(0)$ for the two others.

Comment: Also, $f_{n}$ will not converge in measure, considerind the Lebesgue measure. For the second, $f_{n}$ converges to $f=0$, but not uniformly, according to my opinion.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote? For (b), $f_n(0) = n$...

Comment: Yes, for the last two, $f_{n}(0)=n$

Comment: So it's not really convergent, even pointwise, is it? Not on $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: It would be convergent almost everywhere?

Comment: That, yes. In both cases, only $0$ is an issue for pointwise convergence.

Comment: Ok. So, the first converges to $0$, I am sorry

Comment: Now, an easy way to deal with $L^1$ convergence of the three: what is $\int_\mathbb{R} \lvert f_n - f\rvert=\int_\mathbb{R} f_n $ in all cases?

Comment: in the first case, that integral is 1

Comment: And I think also in the last...

Comment: In all 3. So it does not really converge to 0...

Comment: ok,you are right...

Comment: Then, I dont see how I can find out if converges pointwise to something or uniformy or in measure..I have no idea

Comment: Can you give me a suggestion?it seems that the first converge to $0$, but it doesnt...

Comment: The first does converge to zero on $\mathbb{R}$; it also converges to zero uniformly, but not in $L^1$. Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: For the first, $f_{n}=1/n$, if $x \in [0,1/n]$ and is 0 for $x \notin [0,1/n]$. To study the pointwise convergence, we must calculate lim$f_{n}(x)$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$.

Comment: why does it converges uniformly to 0?

Comment: Fix $x \geq 0$. (for $x < 0$, then $f_n(x) = 0$ for all $n$ and we are done) Then, for $n \geq x$, we have $f_n(x) = 1/n\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$. [Pointwise convergence]

Comment: For the uniform convergence: $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert f_n(x) - f(x)\rvert = \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}} \lvert f_n(x)- 0\rvert = \frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} 0$.

Comment: Ok,I get that, thank you so much!!the second also converge to $0$ almost everywhere

Comment: But I dont think the second one converges uniformly to $0$. Do you agree?

Comment: Indeed - the $\sup$ is something like $n$, now.

Comment: Yes because for $x<0$, that limit is $\infty$.

Comment: $f_n(x) = 0$ for $x< 0$. The sup is then only to take for $x\geq 0$ (or even $x>0$, since the domain of convergence is only $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. But the supremum is still $n$, since $f_n(x)\to n$ when $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: And for the third one, $f_{n}(x)=n$, for $x \in[0,1/n]$ and $0$ for $x$ not in this interval. Does this sequence converges to a function?

Comment: What have you tried? (as mentioned above, it converges pointwise to the zero function on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, and does not converge at $0$. But it definitely does not converge uniformly, since $\sup_{\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}} f_n =n$ for all $n$)

Comment: I dont understand why the third one converges to $0$. I pick an $x$. If $x \in [0,1/n]$, then $f_{n}(x)=n$ and if I calculate lim$f_{n}(x)=n$ as $n$ goes to the infinity, I obtain $\infty$..

Comment: Fix $x > 0$. (it does not converge for $x=0$). Then, for any $n > n_0 = \lceil 1/x \rceil$, we have $x > 1/n$, so $f_n(x) = 0$.

Comment: No worries! ${}{}{}{}$